# Can I shrink 25 GB Lenovo parition my laptop came with?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, lenovo-laptop

I have just bought a new lenovo yoga 720, with a 256 GB ssd. However, the main partition only has 212.23 GB of space allocated. There is a 25 GB partition called "Lenovo" which has about 1.5 GB of drivers in it. I would like to keep these drivers so that my stylus works, so I don't want to completely reinstall Windows.

Would it be a reasonable idea to shrink the Lenovo partition? I would leave some extra space in case there are updates, but it currently has 23 GB of unused space which is 10% of my laptop's total storage.

I plan on eventually dual booting, so I would use the space for the linux distro.

I'm using a Lenovo yoga 720 13", Windows 10.

Comment: The drivers can be moved to a removable storage device, or simply downloaded from the Lenovo website, feel free to shrink the partition.  However, it’s unlikely you will be able to extend your system partition unless you delete it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a recovery disk that came with the computer, you can resize the partition as the drivers should be restored when you run the disk.

Alternatively, you can either copy the drivers to a USB drive or external hard disk, or to somewhere in the C: partition. You could also download them from the Lenovo website.

Comment: There is no recovery disk. Also, could you elaborate how I would move the drivers without breaking things? Thanks

Comment: Are the drivers in a folder on the D: drive? You can just copy the folder over.

Answer (score -1):

You can shrink the program in third party partitioning tools like minitool partition wizard free edition or easeus partition master, as long as this partition is showing up as NTFS in the program.